# Issue with CGI and IIS : This program is blocked by a group policy

Tags: windows, iis, iis-7.5

We have an issue with trend micro APEX ONE.

Since a windows update, the APEX ONE Web console don't work and we got this issue :

> Erreur HTTP 404.2 - Not Found The page you requested cannot be found due to the ISAPI and CGI restriction list settings of the Web server

I checked the ISAPI and CGI restriction and everything is authorized.

I also activated the logging for this website and we found this other issue :
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/96ys5.png)

We didn't create any policy to block this kind of application.

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Stack Overflow is a place for programming questions, not supporting any irrelevant vendor product like the one you refer to. Contact their technical support and let them fix for you.

Comment: Dear Lex Li, we didn't have any issue with product, but mostly with IIS and the CGI module. Sorry if I made a misunderstood

Comment: FRT clearly revealed that this is a vendor CGI console app returning 404.2 for no reason. And that's why I said chasing the vendor is your only option at this moment. Don't bother others as they have no way to help.

Answer (score 0):

This issue occurs because the requested Internet Server API (ISAPI) resource or the requested Common Gateway Interface (CGI) resource is restricted on the computer that is running IIS. To resolve this issue, configure the restriction on the ISAPI and CGI Restrictions page to allow the requested ISAPI resource or the requested CGI resource. Follow these steps to resolve this issue:

1. Select Start, type Inetmgr in the Start Search box, and then select Inetmgr in the Programs list.

   If you're prompted for an administrator password or for confirmation, type the password, or select Continue.
2. Locate the level that you want to configure.
3. In Features view, double-click ISAPI and CGI Restrictions.
4. Right-click the restriction that restricts the requested ISAPI resource or the requested CGI resource, and then select Allow.

More information you can refer to this link: [HTTP Error 404.2 when you visit a web page that is hosted on a computer that is running IIS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/developer/webapps/iis/site-behavior-performance/http-error-402-webpage).

Comment: Dear Samwu, I checked the ISAPI and CGI Restrictions list and everything is already in the list. I also checked that the resource indicated in the error is authorized

Comment: A third party CGI console app can return any error code for its own reasons, so you cannot use a Microsoft 404.2 article to solve this issue.